# Group consecutive working day dates (excluding weekends and holidays)

Tags: r, date

I have data on different persons (`ID`), the dates they have worked (`Date`), and how many hours they have worked each date (`Hours`).

Monday - Friday are considered working days. For each ID, I want to group consecutive working days. Weekends and holidays should be omitted when deciding if working days are consecutive.

Some examples:

If a person worked Monday, Tuesday and Wednesday, then skipped Thursday, and worked again on Friday, then Monday - Wednesday is considered one group and Friday another group.

If a person worked Thursday & Friday one week and Monday & Tuesday the next week, then these four days should be in the same group. Thus, the days in the weekend are omitted when checking if *working* days are consecutive.

If Monday - Friday of one week and Monday - Friday of the next week, then I'd count those whole two weeks as consecutive working days.

I would also like to take into account common US Holidays (e.g. New Year), such that 12/31/2020 to 1/4/2021 would still count as consecutive workdays.

Once the grouping variable is created, I want to sum the working hours in each group.

Example data:

```
df1 = structure(list(ID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 
3, 3), Date = structure(c(18781, 18782, 18785, 18750, 18687, 
18688, 18626, 18627, 18631, 18634), class = "Date"), Hours = c(8, 
8, 8, 16, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")


  ID       Date Hours
1  1 2021-06-03     8
2  1 2021-06-04     8
3  1 2021-06-07     8
4  1 2021-05-03    16
5  2 2021-03-01     8
6  2 2021-03-02     8
7  3 2020-12-30     8
8  3 2020-12-31     8
9  3 2021-01-04     8
10 3 2021-01-07     8
```

I imagine my output to look something like this:

```
 ID      Date1      Date2 Hours
1 1 2021-06-03 2021-06-07    24
# the weekend, June 5-6, is omitted
# when the group of consecutive working days is created
 
2 1 2021-05-03 2021-05-03    16
3 2 2021-03-01 2021-03-02    16

4 3 2020-12-30 2021-01-04    24
# the public holiday (Jan 1) and the weekend (Jan 2-3) are omitted
   
5 3 2021-01-07 2021-01-07     8
```

My top priority is to at least get the consecutive work week figured out, the holiday portion would be an added bonus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `RQuantLib::businessDaysBetween`. For each ID (`by = ID`), calculate the number of business days between each row, i.e. provide vectors of "lag" (`head(Date, -1)`) and "lead" (`tail(Date, -1)`) as `from` and `to` dates. Pick a relevant `calendar` (see **Details** in `?businessDaysBetween`)

For each ID and run of consecutive business days (`by = .(ID, g = cumsum(d != 1L))`), select the first and last date (`from = Date[1]`, `to = Date[.N]`) and sum the Hours (`sum(Hours)`)

```
library(data.table)
library(RQuantLib)
setDT(df1)

df1[ , d := c(1, businessDaysBetween(calendar = "UnitedStates",
                                     from = head(Date, -1), to = tail(Date, -1))),
    by = ID]

df1[ , .(from = Date[1], to = Date[.N], Hours = sum(Hours)),
    by = .(ID, g = cumsum(d != 1L))]

#    ID g       from         to Hours
# 1:  1 0 2021-06-03 2021-06-07    24
# 2:  1 1 2021-05-03 2021-05-03    16
# 3:  2 1 2021-03-01 2021-03-02    16
# 4:  3 1 2020-12-30 2021-01-04    24
# 5:  3 2 2021-01-07 2021-01-07     8
```

---

More convoluted solution (pre-`businessDaysBetween`):

Create a full sequence of dates within each ID (`df1[ , .(Date = seq(min(Date), max(Date), by = "1 day")), by = ID]`). Join with original data on ID and Date (`df1[..., on =.(ID, Date)`). For dates not present in original data, i.e. gaps between (originally) consecutive days, Hours will be `NA`.

Within each ID (`by = ID`), create a run length index based on missing Hours (`rleid(is.na(Hours))`). For rows with missing Hours (`d[is.na(Hours)`), i.e. the gaps in the original time series, for each ID and run (`by = .(ID, r)`), check if `all` dates are either a weekend (`wday(Date) %in% c(1, 7)`) or (`|`) a public holiday* (`Date %in% as.Date(holidayNYSE(unique(year(Date))))`), and create an index variable, ix.

For original rows and weekend/holiday gaps (`!is.na(Hours) | ix`), create a grouping variable of consecutive dates (`g = cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(Date) != 1L))`). For each ID and run of consecutive dates (`by = .(ID, g)`), select the first and last date (`from = Date[1], to = Date[.N]`) and sum the Hours (`sum(Hours, na.rm = TRUE)`)

```
library(data.table)
library(timeDate)
setDT(df1)

d = df1[df1[ , .(Date = seq(min(Date), max(Date), by = "1 day")), by = ID],
    on = .(ID, Date)]

d[ , r := rleid(is.na(Hours)), by = ID]

d[is.na(Hours), ix := all(
    wday(Date) %in% c(1, 7) |
      Date %in% as.Date(holidayNYSE(unique(year(Date)))))
, by = .(ID, r)]


d[!is.na(Hours) | ix, .(Date, Hours, g = cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(Date) != 1L))),
  by = ID][
  , .(from = Date[1], to = Date[.N],
    Hours = sum(Hours, na.rm = TRUE)),
  by = .(ID, g)] 

#    ID g       from         to Hours
# 1:  1 1 2021-05-03 2021-05-03    16
# 2:  1 2 2021-06-03 2021-06-07    24
# 3:  2 1 2021-03-01 2021-03-02    16
# 4:  3 1 2020-12-30 2021-01-04    24
# 5:  3 2 2021-01-07 2021-01-07     8
```

---

*Please see the [`timeDate` manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/timeDate/timeDate.pdf) for other definitions of holiday.